# How can I use a pair key for encryption with RSA algorithm?

Tags: c#, java, encryption, rsa

I googled it but I couldn't find any useful answer!

I'm going to use a pair key (generated with a c sharp application) in a java application.

But RSA key generator in c sharp return a XML like this :

```
<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>rFsMn+idg8jmVMk249DzJc7AFft3+/jcnYDTh9wHee3tgFu1gBRh7e+ao+MWq7NEN0N7kUHa7O4c/ND2Ahcx/h4mXD5KDoixFRBUsxYqCJVA68qYJ7vozVPMjNr4jeOo1xt+oevO5+mUWtcaib5Iw51u1Jq/6qCqLsm8Eq3cnsE=</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent><P>5aqTyz3GH655H+vO/BzJvFzpILpxLwXZEvqp3l3NYXKqP0tdkY1g36o6M9YodI3h8ho4VFYofIqA1+V0qPkuDQ==</P><Q>wB45uljBS8Z+WGRE1cRdpZb5aKUv76uLlCp6agtPBBhjXNIQrN8MpOCTvZM2cOsuYpYhDtnwsTY9KKXdBmv6hQ==</Q><DP>KB474uzPhwk7L1BJv9BnjPfN4WGwE765xI70zVslXThidNv9ZEeF/IwHzrZCKtn99gSOgmzqdZbcGtqCHmIooQ==</DP><DQ>eLnFrvsdJJ/sP2Fq/CX0bx0rR34eXG6hPI9g84h9s+YbcnWy8t8LVASn8oYyvMydDminB20e2k1qK0PnW6S4/Q==</DQ><InverseQ>rlPpLse8LJ0KRglnu2D1xzJT90QqzS3o80P0WTpUvm95mF5d8YaVj/d9W7FBdgZ98y6Q7of+wLCmYGKLg56wYQ==</InverseQ><D>Gs8mzZDPP3p2aWXLBfCwgYcBVeoBpc318wHg5VcSSqL5uGeLedqxyOLmOOvP0PFXgQkcJWIK/aOkGqcePQECo3TNiK+uLSwc97V3spZah70FFJVyh23Y+o0wlRGHAm5Nj9QieHlVwhgJPkNUJYgH9qkwB9aCpl+rdAG3da2fQ2E=</D></RSAKeyValue>
```

And java need an KeyPair object.

How can I generate a KeyPair from string ?

Comment: First things first, do you know how RSA works?

Comment: yes, I know about it!

Comment: That looks like it's just Base64.

Comment: @chrylis Could u explain it please?!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527423/porting-net-rsa-xml-keys-to-java?rq=1, which even has the good answer

Comment: @OlegEstekhin Thank u so much:)
But what did u search to find it ?!