# Java RSA key to C# XML Key: Change RSA PublicKey and PrivateKey in Java to C# XML RSAKeyValue XML string?

Tags: java, c#, rsa, communication

`RSACryptoServiceProvider` in C# accpets keys in format like this:

For public keys:

```
<RSAKeyValue>
    <Modulus>21wEnTU+mcD2w0Lfo1Gv4rtcSWsQJQTNa6gio05AOkV/Er9w3Y13Ddo5wGtjJ19402S71HUeN0vbKILLJdRSES5MHSdJPSVrOqdrll/vLXxDxWs/U0UT1c8u6k/Ogx9hTtZxYwoeYqdhDblof3E75d9n2F0Zvf6iTb4cI7j6fMs=</Modulus>
    <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
</RSAKeyValue>
```

For private keys:

```
<RSAKeyValue>
    <Modulus>21wEnTU+mcD2w0Lfo1Gv4rtcSWsQJQTNa6gio05AOkV/Er9w3Y13Ddo5wGtjJ19402S71HUeN0vbKILLJdRSES5MHSdJPSVrOqdrll/vLXxDxWs/U0UT1c8u6k/Ogx9hTtZxYwoeYqdhDblof3E75d9n2F0Zvf6iTb4cI7j6fMs=</Modulus>
    <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
    <P>/aULPE6jd5IkwtWXmReyMUhmI/nfwfkQSyl7tsg2PKdpcxk4mpPZUdEQhHQLvE84w2DhTyYkPHCtq/mMKE3MHw==</P>
    <Q>3WV46X9Arg2l9cxb67KVlNVXyCqc/w+LWt/tbhLJvV2xCF/0rWKPsBJ9MC6cquaqNPxWWEav8RAVbmmGrJt51Q==</Q>
    <DP>8TuZFgBMpBoQcGUoS2goB4st6aVq1FcG0hVgHhUI0GMAfYFNPmbDV3cY2IBt8Oj/uYJYhyhlaj5YTqmGTYbATQ==</DP>
    <DQ>FIoVbZQgrAUYIHWVEYi/187zFd7eMct/Yi7kGBImJStMATrluDAspGkStCWe4zwDDmdam1XzfKnBUzz3AYxrAQ==</DQ>
    <InverseQ>QPU3Tmt8nznSgYZ+5jUo9E0SfjiTu435ihANiHqqjasaUNvOHKumqzuBZ8NRtkUhS6dsOEb8A2ODvy7KswUxyA==</InverseQ>
    <D>cgoRoAUpSVfHMdYXW9nA3dfX75dIamZnwPtFHq80ttagbIe4ToYYCcyUz5NElhiNQSESgS5uCgNWqWXt5PnPu4XmCXx6utco1UVH8HGLahzbAnSy6Cj3iUIQ7Gj+9gQ7PkC434HTtHazmxVgIR5l56ZjoQ8yGNCPZnsdYEmhJWk=</D>
</RSAKeyValue>
```

I create my key pair in Java like this:

```
KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
kpg.initialize(1024);
KeyPair kp = kpg.genKeyPair();
PublicKey publicKey = kp.getPublic();
PrivateKey privateKey = kp.getPrivate();
```

**Edit:**

I want to know how can I convert keys which I created in Java to C# XML keys?
Questions like [Porting .Net RSA xml keys to Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527423/porting-net-rsa-xml-keys-to-java?noredirect=1&lq=1) do what I want in reverse direction. It read keys from C# and generate them for use inside Java.
I need to convert java keys to C# XML keys.

Comment: I am not sure so I am not voting to close, but could this be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527423/porting-net-rsa-xml-keys-to-java?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto The question you linked is get keys in C# and convert to keys in Java. I want to do it on reverse direction. Generate keys in Java and use them inside C#.

Answer (score 0):

From [RSAPublicKey (5.24 API Documentation)](http://javadoc.iaik.tugraz.at/iaik_jce/old/iaik/security/rsa/RSAPublicKey.html#method_summary) there are the methods on the Java class RSAPublicKey

```
java.math.BigInteger    getModulus()        Returns the modulus of the public key.
java.math.BigInteger    getPublicExponent() Returns the public exponent of the public key.
```

So from there you should be able to concatenate a well-formed Xml string.

This maybe of use as well [How to Generate RSA Keys in Java _ Novixys Software Dev Blog](http://www.novixys.com/blog/how-to-generate-rsa-keys-java/)

This [also quite close](http://csharpforwindesk.blogspot.com/2018/02/c-elliptic-curve-digital-signatures.html), it shows Xml keys being communicated between two components of C# code, although it differs slightly in that it is Elliptic Curve and Not RSA.  The key method there is [`FromXmlString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsa.fromxmlstring(v=vs.110).aspx)

Quite simply, you call methods on the Java object to extract the modulus and exponent, you build the string, save it to a file and then in C# load from file into a string and pass into [`FromXmlString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsa.fromxmlstring(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I want to know how can I convert these values to XML Key Value in C#?

Comment: There is one important small wrinkle that needs to be included. `BigInteger.toByteArray()` almost does exactly what is needed. However, about half the time it returns a byte array with a leading zero because *if* the higher-order byte of the BigInteger would be >= 128 then a leading zero byte is prepended. This a twos-complement-like encoding that accommodates negative numbers. However, the relevant [XML standards](https://www.w3.org/TR/xkms2/) don't recognize negative numbers so this zero byte has to be removed when it's present prior to base64 encoding the array.

Comment: @JamesKPolk: thanks, I do not normally code in Java, I saw this question on the C# queue.  Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for your update. I did know all this stuff. But still conversion from PublicKey object to XML key for C# seems tricky. XML key got parameters like `InverseQ` which must be calculated. Even we know `modulus` and `exponent` but their representation and conversion from byte array to string and base64 need enough care. I was looking for a code snippet to do that.

Comment: are you sure you need anything other than modulus and exponent?  I'd run an experiment look to use a few data items as possible.  You might be surprised.

Comment: @JamesKPolk Leading zero in byte array when converted to base64 will cause error? I mean you say that leading zeros when converted to base 64 are not removed and we will have an string with prefix of zeros?

Comment: Cause an error? No, it will run without error but it won't be the correct format.